# Change label and icon positions of tableview's cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel

it' possible to change position oh image and lable of my tableview's cell?
I would not use CustomCell..

I have tried this (for the label)..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else
        return cell;

    UIImage *image = nil;

            cell.textLabel.text = @"text label";
            UILabel *label = cell.textLabel; 
            CGRect frame = label.frame;
            frame.origin.x = 62;
            frame.origin.y = 62;
            label.frame = frame;
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];


    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
```

}

Comment: [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) you may refer to this doc. It includes default & custome cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please take one UIview..and give frame size same as cell size...after that add label in that view...also whatever u want to add..add as a subview in that view...than add that view in cell .

All The Best

Answer (score 0):

```
//table cell contains title,date,image

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
        {


               static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell =nil;
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

            if (cell == nil) 

            {
                       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
            }

       //tittle label     

        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame] ;
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;  
            titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            titleLabel.text = [currentTweet title];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

    //date label

        UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:dateFrame];
            dateLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
            dateLabel.text = [currentTweet dateCreated];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];

    //image view
        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(2, 8, 40,50);    
          self.customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
          customImage.image =image;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.customImage];
        return cell;
```